# Bootstrap responsive image align bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In the following fiddle, I want the 275x275 image to align to the bottom of the row:

https://jsfiddle.net/2n2x2bko/

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><img class="img-responsive logo center-block" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Work</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">About</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x575"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/275x275"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">App</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There doesn't seem to a vertical alignment equivalent of .center-block, any ideas?

Comment: It is at the bottom of the row. what exactly do you want?

Comment: I do not see the 275x275 at the bottom of the row. I see it at the top of the row.

Comment: @Huey can you send image how exactly you want?

Comment: I was modeling this after this portfolio website: faithlung.com

Comment: @Huey: See this: https://jsfiddle.net/2n2x2bko/3/

Comment: That just has the 275x275 underneath the other image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any class in Bootstrap v3 that aligns element vertically but you can use the below solutions to achieve your desire situation.

1. `display:inline-block;`.([don't forget to remove spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)) [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/2n2x2bko/5/)

```css
[class*=valign-] [class*=col] {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}

[class=valign-top] [class*=col] {
  vertical-align: top;
}

[class=valign-middle] [class*=col] {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

[class=valign-bottom] [class*=col] {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><img class="img-responsive logo center-block" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Work</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">About</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row valign-bottom">
    <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x575"></div><div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive bottom-img" src="http://placehold.it/275x275"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">App</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2. `display: flex;` [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/2n2x2bko/5/)

```css
[class*=valign-bottom"]{
 display: flex;
align-items:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12"><img class="img-responsive logo center-block" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">Work</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">About</div>
    <div class="col-md-4">Contact</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row valign-bottom">
    <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x575"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive bottom-img" src="http://placehold.it/275x275"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">App</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">App</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems really slow. Cant this be done better with js?

Comment: What do u mean by "This seems really slow"?

Comment: @Alex: What's the advantage of using an attribute selector? For instance, I think I can achieve a similar result without it: https://jsfiddle.net/6uf9bg5t/

Comment: @Huey It was another way that I used for selecting element.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to make the image element relative to its parent row. So change the images row to :

```
<div class="row alignRow">
   <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/600x575"></div>
   <div class="col-md-6 alignImage"><img class="img-responsive bottom-img" src="http://placehold.it/275x275"></div>
</div>
```

And add this css:

```
.alignRow {
    position: relative;
 }
.alignImage {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
 }
```

Note that this will mess up its allignment with its siblimg image, so the best way to do this would be to make them both absolute and then specify some width values.

Take a look at your updated jsfiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2n2x2bko/1/)

Comment: This seems to screw up the responsiveness when you make the width smaller.